# Review first post / late answers: show other answers as well

Tags: feature-request, review, usability

when I am reviewing an answer, I only see the answer to be reviewed and the corresponding question.

If the answer actually answers the question - at least to some extent - then I *have to* look at other answers to see if it is not a duplicate. This is sometimes problematic, especially when using a smartphone...

For convenience, I would suggest one of the following:

- Show all the answers in review mode,
- Introduce a "show other answers" button,
- Show at least accepted answer - if any.

(The last option would not quite solve the problem, though)

Comment: Is it possible/desirable to open another browser tab to look at the other answers? (... I can do it on my phone.)

Comment: @ChrisNash: if is possible of course, but it is less convenient than seeing all the answers right away. Besides, one may think it's not even needed to take a look at other answers...